# dylib miss some class when build in release mode

Tags: ios, frameworks, dylib

I want to build a dylib for [Xtrace](https://github.com/johnno1962/Xtrace).

I just copy `Xtrace.h` and `Xtrace.mm` into a template framework project.

But it is very strange, when I build in release mode Xtrace class is missing in the dylib, but debug mode is ok.Other file is just fine.

[Here is the project I create.](https://github.com/CodeLife2012/XtraceDylib)

Comment: How have you confirmed this?  Link failures?  Using `nm`?

Comment: Have you tried actually using it?  It's not clear to me what MachOView is showing you; perhaps it's just showing you the debug symbols, which you would expect to me missing on the release version.

Comment: I can't find  the  class in`_objc_classname`  section, other class has no problem. And Can't find the class in runtime too.Maybe you can take a look  at the [project](https://github.com/CodeLife2012/XtraceDylib);